# Use of 可能な他 in a sentence

Tags: translation

I have the following sentence that has been troubling me.

> 準備術式や詠唱を必要とする大魔法のプロセスをある程度省略し、高速発動させる事が可能な他、魔力を充填したページを武器・装甲として使用可能。

Yes it's unfortunatelly Anime bs, but I put it in it's entirety for context's sake. It is from a description of a certain item.

The first segment is easy enough to translate:

> Somewhat shortens the process of Big Magic that requires technique preparation and arias

the part I have issues with is the next one:

> 高速発動させる事が可能な他

specifically the role of here 他 and how it's used in the form of

> subject が可能な他

高速発動させる of course is high speed activation (of magic). But I don't really see how one should then put that together with the 可能な他 which is I think possible others.

As of now I think this means that other types of magic, that is not BIG magic, whose cast time is a bit shortened, are significantly sped up since presumably they weren't as long in preparation initially...

But that's still wierd to me. If I lacked context and got a sentence of the like:

> verb 事が adjectiveな noun

I'd assume it's trying to say that the action described by the verb is somehow the noun described by the adjective...

---

**Edit:**

I'm editing the question, to add some more context since I was not able to get the answers I got, and how they would fit here.

The item in question is a magical/mage's tool used for doing magic. The user of the item is known for long cast time but massive damage spells. Such spells have been referred to as big magic before.

While 詠唱 is more singing chanting, in this verse, in translations "aria" was used, and it basically describes the incantation performed by the mage to activate magic. So shortening/abbreviating the "aria" and other preparatory tasks makes sense.

発動 is activation or in the parlance of the setting the triggering of magic. This term is used for activation/putting into effect/casting magic.

Mana, pages etc. Previously one of parts of the setting was the ability to store mana (魔力) into objects that can then later be used for doing things. This user in particular has had a book before where pages were composed of mana. So the last segment seems to say that the object can be used as weapon or armor, which is in some way connected/described by pages filled with mana.

I'm kinda beggining to think that all fragments basically share として使用可能 as an ending, but I"m still confused by how 他 and ページを武器・装甲 fit here

Comment: FYI 詠唱 doesn't mean "aria" here (although that would be highly amusing).

Comment: I know. It means more incantation. Something you do to make the magicky happen. But the term aria has been in use from before my time for the same. Blame first fansubs for that.

Comment: It may be this piece of grammar that confuses you, which this construction is built upon: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14541/7810, cf. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19139/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56569/7810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here is how I interpret the sentence:

> 準備術式や詠唱を必要とする大魔法のプロセスをある程度省略し、高速発動させる事が可能な他、魔力を充填したページを武器・装甲として使用可能。
>
> Other than being capable of somewhat abbreviating the process of Great Magics that require preparatory formulation and(/or) incantation and (thus) speedily initiating [said Great Magics], [the item] makes it possible to use pages charged with magic as weapons and armor.

And a slimmed-down version:

> Enables swift casting of Great Magics by abbreviating the process of preparatory formulation and(/or) incantation. Also enables magic-charged pages to be used as weapons and armor.

The thing with「他」is that when a clause, verb phrase or some other adnominal phrase XXX modifies it, the whole phrase「XXX他」(always, as far as I know) means something to the effect of "other than XXX" (or "apart from X"), rather than forming a noun phrase that is interpretable in English as being headed by "(an)other" and having XXX as a modifier. (that is, not interpretable as the noun phrase *(an)other [who/which...]*, *[V-ing] (an)other*, or  *[adjective/determinative] (an)other*)

Now, in the sentence in question, 「準備術式や詠唱を必要とする大魔法のプロセスをある程度省略し、高速発動させる事が可能な」 is a modifier for「他」. And if you remember, when something modifies「他」, the resulting phrase means "**other than** XXX", so the who phrase "準備術式や詠唱を必要とする大魔法のプロセスをある程度省略し、高速発動させる事が可能な**他**" will be translated as something like  "**other than** being capable of somewhat abbreviating the process of Great Magics that require preparatory formulation and(/or) incantation and (thus) speedily initiating [said Great Magics]", like above.

(If the head noun were「アイテム」 or some other "normal" noun instead of this little weirdo 「他」 and the whole phrase went like 「準備術式や詠唱を必要とする大魔法のプロセスをある程度省略し、高速発動させる事が可能なアイテム」, it would be translated as a noun phrase as you would expect, but no,「他」 just has to be different.)

As to why a noun phrase like this one can stand freely within a sentence without a particle like 「に」... well, I can't say for sure, but I reckon it involves the omission of the particle and then reanalysis of 「他」 into a [副助詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E#%E5%89%AF%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E) (like what happened with happened with 位 and 程) or into a 接続助詞 (like 時 and 所). (Come to think of it, the English "other than XXX," also behaves like this, though possibly through an unlike process.)

Answer (score 2):

A ほか B means "B beside A".

So, …省略し…可能な他、…として使用可能 means "it's available as ..., besides you can omit ... and activate it in high speed.

Since 可能 is a na-adjective, it takes な to connect to a noun.

- e.g 彼らが自由な方がいい: I hope that they are free
- それが可能なことを見れば: considering that it's capable.

Comment: Ummm, I don't exactly get your explanation. Could you give me what do you think should be the translation?

Comment: I can't because there are too much technical jargon. Anyway, 発動させることが可能な他 is "besides you can activate" as above.

Comment: I think the translation got the clause order backwards. Shouldn't it be "You can omit ... and activate it in high speed; besides, it's available as..."? (Also, 使用可能 seems to describes "魔力を充填したページ", not the item, so translating the second clause as "it's available as..." might not be the best way...)

Comment: @goldbrick Ah, thanks. I though "besides 節" was possible.

Answer (score 2):

の他に means "besides", "in addition". 可能な is attributive form of a na-adjective 可能だ. For example, このパソコンは(で)、テレビを見ることが可能な他、ゲームもできる(You can watch TV with this personal computer, in addition to that, you can play games with it as well).

The sentence means "You can activate it quickly with shortening of the process of Big Magic that requires technique preparation and spells, in addition to that, you can use the pages that is filled up with magic as weapons and armors."

Comment: Soo, you are saying it kinda acts as a connector. Something like が does? So part 2 is just an extension of part 1 (it's usable for abbreviating and engaging big scale magic) and then 他 just connects it to the next part?

Comment: You can think 他 as に is omitted in 他に. So the part 2 sentence can follow after the part 1 sentence without ending the sentence. By the way, is が used as a connector?

Answer (score 1):

> 準備術式や詠唱を必要とする大魔法のプロセスをある程度省略し、高速発動させる事が**可能な他**、魔力を充填したページを武器・装甲として**使用可能**。

与えられた文から修飾部分{しゅうしょくぶぶん}を大幅{おおはば}に削除{さくじょ}して簡単{かんたん}な文として書き直{なお}すと (1) のようになります。

(1)　高速発動させる事が**可能な[他]{ほか}**、ページを武器・装甲として**使用可能**。

ここで (1) を良くみますと、主語{しゅご}が省略{しょうりゃく}されていることが分{わ}かります。また、文末{ぶんまつ}を見ますと、文が完結{かんけつ}していないことがわかります。主語をＡとして、また、文を完結させますと、例{たと}えば (2) のようになります。

(2)　**Ａは**高速発動させる事が可能な他、ページを武器・装甲として使用可能**である**。

これは、例えば (3) と同じような文の構造{こうぞう}をもっていることが分かります。

(3)　スプーンはスープをすくうことが可能な他、背面{はいめん}を茹｛ゆ｝でたジャガイモを圧{お}し潰{つぶ}す道具{どうぐ}として使用可能である。

(3) のままでも意味{いみ}が通{つう}じますので問題{もんだい}はありませんが、(3-1) あるいは (3-2) のように書き換{か}えると更{さら}に良い日本語の文になります。

(3-1)　スプーンはスープをすくうことが可能な**道具である**他、背面を茹でたジャガイモを圧し潰す道具として**も**使用可能である。
(3-2)　スプーンはスープをすくうことが可能**である**他、背面を茹でたジャガイモを圧し潰す道具として**も**使用可能である。

(3) をもっと簡単な文に書き直すと (4-1) あるいは (4-2) になります。

(4-1)　スプーンはスープをすくうことが可能な道具である。それ以外に、スプーンの背面を茹でたジャガイモを圧し潰す道具としても使用可能である。
(4-2)　スプーンはスープをすくうことが可能である。それ以外に、スプーンの背面を茹でたジャガイモを圧し潰す道具としても使用可能である。

(4-1) あるいは (4-2) をヒントとしてＯＰが疑問{ぎもん}に思っている最初{さいしょ}の文を理解{りかい}してください。